# Failed to find class `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$TimestampDeserializer` for handlingvaluesof type `java.sql.Timestamp`

Tags: micronaut, jackson-databind, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, micronaut-data

```
Failed to find class `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$TimestampDeserializer` for handling values of type
 `java.sql.Timestamp`, problem: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$TimestampDeserializer
```

getting this error while running via native image on lambda;
in Local  its running fine

Seems like while fetching a timestamp from Database(also in timestamp) its giving error.

graalvm :20.3.2
gradle: 7
java: 8

tried adding the following in the reflection.Json file

```
 {
        "name": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers",
        "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
        "allPublicConstructors": true,
        "allDeclaredMethods": true,
        "allPublicMethods": true,
        "allDeclaredClasses": true,
        "allPublicClasses": true,
        "allDeclaredFields": true
    },
```

tried adding in build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.14.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reflection config should be mentioning different class,

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$TimestampDeserializer`

rather than

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers`

Comment: tried adding as you suggested, no luck